# On the validity of a manual-calculation-friendly variation of the Legendre's formula: $\nu_p(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\rfloor$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The Legendre's formula gives $\alpha$ in

$$p^\alpha || n!$$

where $p$ is a prime number.

---

To calculate $\nu_p(n!)$ on paper, one should normally find the quotients $q_i$ in these equations by long division and then sum them up:

$$n=p^i q_i+r_i, \quad 0\le r_i \lt p^i$$

So we will divide $n$ by $p^i$'s multiple times.

The variation I stumbled upon is using the *previous* quotient and divide by $p$. This method of using recursive divisions is indeed relatively faster as the divisor remains small instead of growing exponentially (as it does in the first method). It is basically saying:

$$Q_0:=n$$
$$Q_i=pQ_{i+1}+R_{i+1}, \quad 0 \le R_i \lt p$$

Manipulating them a bit, we get:

$$n=p^i Q_i + \sum_{j=1}^i p^{j-1} R_j$$

As you see, the equations look similar to those of the first method. But I doubt if this variation will give the correct result because I couldn't prove $\forall i; q_i = Q_i$. This is my approach:

If I prove $0 \le \sum_{j=1}^i p^{j-1} R_j \lt p^i$, then $q_i = Q_i$ and the two methods are equivalent.

$$0\le R_i \lt p$$
$$0\le p^{i-1}R_i \lt p^i$$
$$0\le\sum_{i=1}^k p^{i-1} R_i \lt \sum_{i=1}^k p^i=p\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}$$

I should just check if $p\frac{p^k-1}{p-1} \le p^k$:

$$p(p^k-1) \le p^k (p-1)$$
$$-p \le -p^k$$
$$p \ge p^k$$

Which is wrong since prime numbers are greater than one.

Because of the essence of the proof I used, there might be another approach which works and can prove the two methods are the same.

---

**Is the second method valid?**

Comment: Yes, that's a direct consequence of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718560/prove-bigg-lfloor-frac-lfloor-x-rfloor-m-bigg-rfloor-bigg-lfloor-fracx) for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer That totally solved my issue. Thank you!
I think I just couldn't abstract that core issue from the whole problem, making the question seem more complex than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out in comments, your question boils down to [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718560/prove-bigg-lfloor-frac-lfloor-x-rfloor-m-bigg-rfloor-bigg-lfloor-fracx) which I will explain a little more.

If $y=\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p}\bigg\rfloor$ then $y$ is an integer and $yp \leqslant n \leqslant (y+1)p$

so, since $yp$ is an integer, we have $yp \leqslant \lfloor n \rfloor \leqslant n \leqslant (y+1)p$

and so $\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{\lfloor n \rfloor }{p}\bigg\rfloor = y = \bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p}\bigg\rfloor$.

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing, as $n$ usually denotes an integer.  But then of course $\lfloor n \rfloor = n$. Actually, aren't you just repeating the answer in the linked question?

Comment: Yes, all I did was switch the variables that pertain to the OP's question.